# How to pass a variable to template in Django

Tags: python, django, templates, view

I'm pretty new to django and after a few hours of trying, nothing works.

I have a views.py:

```
class sspView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'ssp/sspTableView.html'
    context_object_name = 'ssp'
    message = "yo, this is the message"

    def message(request):
        return render(request, 'ssp/sspTableView.html', {'message': message})

    def get_queryset(self):
        return googleData.objects.order_by('date')
```

I have a template.html:

```
{% if ssp %}
<p>total click is: {{ message }}</p>
<table>
    {% for googleData in ssp %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ googleData.date }}</td>
        <td>{{ googleData.account }}</td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
{% endif %}
```

Table renders perfectly, but that message just won't show.

Thank you.

Comment: Note that class names [should](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions) normally use the CapWords convention.

Comment: @ErnestTen  I will keep that in mind, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [add extra context](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/class-based-views/#adding-extra-context) using `get_context_data` method:

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(sspView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['message'] = 'Hello, context!'
    return context
```

Comment: this works like a champ ~~ I came across get_context_data function but didn't try, thank you !

Answer (score 2):

Write only following line or move line outside of `if` loop.

```
<p>total click is: {{ message }}</p>
```

**Why not visible?**

because there is `if` condition written in template.
  `{% if ssp %}`

Comment: The text "total click is" shows. But the message variable doesn't go through.

Comment: @viviwill: ok, can you hard code message in code? like `(request, 'ssp/sspTableView.html', {'message': "I am message"})`